# source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash not found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am pretty new to Ubuntu and am have some issues. I installed ros kinetic and can see everything located within the opt folder. However, as soon as I try to source it like the instructions say to do it says that the source is not found. Did I do something wrong during installation? I'm super stuck :/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246500/source-/opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash-not-found/) by [nordm031](https://answers.ros.org/users/28346/nordm031/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I installed ros kinetic and can see everything located within the opt folder.

Can you please tell us how you installed ROS? Which tutorials did you follow (if any)? Which version of Ubuntu is this (probably 16.04 / Xenial)?

What is the output of:

```
ls -al /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash
```

(please add it to your question by *editing* it)

Also, can you check you have the `ros-kinetic-catkin` package installed? Something like

```
dpkg -l | grep ros-kinetic-catkin
```

Should give you that information.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1